# What populates the /sys and /dev directories

Tags: linux, drivers, kernel-modules, udev, devices

My understanding is that the `/sys` directory contains files explaining information about the different devices. How and when does this directory get populated?

Exploring a Linux system here for example and I see the `/sys/bus/i2c/devices` directory contains some files for I2C devices.

Is it a job of the I2C device driver / module in this case to create these files there?

Then regarding the `/dev` directory, does the device driver / module populate this also? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The filesystem that is mounted on `/sys` is the `sysfs` filesystem. `sysfs` is an example of a so-called *virtual filesystem* or *pseudo filesystem*. These filesystems are called "virtual" because they do not actually represent physically stored files but rather, they *synthesize* a file-like view of non-file data structures.

So, `sysfs` is a filesystem which synthesizes a file-like view of the internals of the kernel.

It is the job of every driver / module to register itself and its data structures with the Kernel Object Model in such a way that the rest of the kernel can "understand" these data structures. But it is generally not the job of the driver to then translate this Object Model into directories and files in `sysfs`, that job is performed by `sysfs` itself. Only for device-specific information does the module have to tell `sysfs` how to represent it.

The most well-known and oldest of example of a virtual filesystem is the `procfs` filesystem, which is usually mounted at `/proc`. `procfs` was first implemented in Unix V8 in 1984. From there, it was ported to SVR4 in 1991, it inspired a much more comprehensive implementation in Plan 9, which was in turn copied into 4.4BSD. Interestingly, both FreeBSD and OpenBSD have phased out `procfs` and macOS never had it in the first place.

Linux gained a `procfs` in 1992. Traditionally, in Linux, `procfs` was used to export all sorts of different data to user space, not use process-related data. However, for a long time, there was no standard governing the way this data gets exposed, and so you can find a wide variety of different styles: some data is exposed in a way that is easily human-readable, but is very hard to parse with a script, other is optimized to be machine-readable. Some complex data is represented as a single large file, other is represented as a directory with one file per constituent part.

`sysfs` was introduced to clean up this mess, with strict rules about how data should be represented.

Regarding `/dev`, there is a varied story. Traditionally, `/dev` is just a normal directory on the root filesystem. The system administrator is responsible for creating the device nodes using the `mknod` utility. Over time, Unix distributions would start shipping pre-made scripts the system administrator can run to create the most important device nodes, and even further on, the installer for the Unix distribution would pre-populate the directory with the often-used device nodes, so generally, there would be no need for the system administrator to create them manually.

With growing support for hot-pluggable devices (especially after the introduction of USB and Firewire), and Linux pushing more and more into markets where there is typically no experienced "system administrator" available (e.g. consumer desktops), it became clear that neither having the system administrator manually create and delete device nodes whenever you plug or unplug a device, nor pre-creating every single device node for every single possible device was a viable option.

Therefore, `devfs` was created, which is a virtual filesystem that automatically contains device nodes for every device discovered by the kernel. For a while, `devfs` and the distribution-specific approaches to handling plug&play by trying to detect devices and running scripts to create device nodes existed side-by-side.

There was some criticism about the quality and implementation style of `devfs`. Most notably, it was criticized that there is actually no need for creating and deleting device nodes to be handled inside the kernel at all, and `devfs` came about at a time, where the Linux developers started working to *remove* stuff from the kernel that does not absolutely need to be there.

One of the mantras of Linux kernel development is that "mechanisms can be in the kernel, policy must be in user space", and `devfs` violates that, because it puts the *policy decision* "what name should I give to this device" in the kernel.

As a result, `udev` was developed. `udev` consists of multiple components, most importantly, a daemon which uses `sysfs` (and some other resources such as *udev events*) to get informed about any change to the devices available in the system, and then uses a set of user-definable *rules* to create and delete corresponding device nodes. This does not require any special support from the kernel, since the information `udev` needs is already available in `sysfs` and elsewhere, and `/dev` can once again be just a normal filesystem.

Nowadays, most Linux distributions use `udev`, but also, alternatives to `udev` have been developed such as `eudev` (a fork of `udev`) or `mdev` (a minimal `udev` replacement based on BusyBox intended for lightweight resource-constrained systems). This is one of the big advantages of moving functionality out of the kernel into user space: in general, there can only be one instance of a certain piece of functionality in the kernel, whereas it is pretty easy to have competing implementations in user space that can be easily swapped out. In general, competition leads to better quality.

Typically, when using `udev`, a temporary filesystem is used for `/dev`: that way, you don't have to worry about cleaning up stale device nodes after a system crash or reboot: since you always start with an empty filesystem, `udev` will only re-create the device nodes for devices that are actually present.

You can use the root filesystem and simply delete the contents of `/dev` somewhere in the boot scripts (although that gets tricky since you also need at least some working device nodes in `/dev` to boot) or you can use `tmpfs` (which only exists in memory), where you have the same problem.

In order to solve this bootstrapping problem of how to get `udev` to work when you need at least some device nodes to get `udev` to work but `udev` is the one creating the device nodes, `devtmpfs` was developed.

Now, in some sense, `devtmpfs` is very similar to `devfs`, so you might ask yourself, why is `devtmpfs` accepted when `devfs` wasn't? Well, there are two important differences: one hint is already in the name "`devtmpfs`". `devtmpfs` is building on `tmpfs`: why would you want to re-invent how to represent files in RAM, when `tmpfs` has already solved the problem for you? (That was another criticism leveled at `devfs`, that it duplicated a bunch of functionality that already existed in `tmpfs`.)

The other difference is that `devtmpfs` is very simplistic in how it created the device nodes and leaves the more complex stuff to `udev`. For example, `devtmpfs` does not try to implement any complex rules for how to name devices, it just uses very simple names, and then `udev` can use its user-defined rulesets to create symbolic links from user-defined names to the kernel-defined ones.

So, in a modern Linux system, you would typically have `devtmpfs` mounted at `/dev` which creates some barebones device nodes, you would have `sysfs` mounted at `/sys` which exposes the internal information of the kernel as files, and you have `udev` running in user space, which receives updates from the kernel via `sysfs` and udev events and creating links to those barebones devices based on user-defined rules.

There is a *lot* more to this, but this is the 10000km overview.

Answer (score 4):

`/sys` content is populated by kernel `sysfs` filesystem driver. Some generic nodes are created automatically when driver or device registered, some driver- and device-specific nodes are created by device driver itself.
`/dev` content on most of modern systems is maintained by `udev` framework in userspace, which is usually a part of `systemd` package. There are alternatives to `udev` for embedded systems, e.g. `mdev`. But kernel also provices support of `devtmpfs` filesystem which has reduced functionality and used by `udev` as a base.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So hypothetically, if I have to write a completely new kernel driver from scratch to control an I2C device, it must communicate with the sysfs filesystem driver?

Comment: @Engineer999 It depends what your device is and what does it do. If i understand correctly, it is I2C-controlled device. All sysfs nodes for I2C device will be created automatically as device is bound to I2C-controller. But what functionality your driver will provide? For example, if it provides GPIO over I2C, you should register GPIO controller with `gpiochip_add_data()` and this will create all gpio-related nodes. The same for other subsystems. But if you want to provide some additional nodes then you should communicate with sysfs driver, the API is in `linux/sysfs.h`

Comment: I see on my system here that there is the I2C keypad input device. This also appears in /dev/input/event0 . Where and how exactly does this event input file get created also ?

Comment: @Engineer999 Keypad driver registers input device with `input_register_device()` (or something similar). Kernel's input subsystem creates corresponding sysfs nodes in `/sys/class/input/` and registers character device. Kernel's character device subsystem creates corresponding nodes in `/sys/dev/char`. Then it may be different scenarios depending on system. Either kernel creates `/dev/input/event0` node in `devtmpfs` or `udev` creates it from userspace according to `/sys/` nodes and udev rules. In any case driver has nothing to do with this file creation, it just registers input device.